# Find NaN's in pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code to check if a certain cell in my Dataframe is empty. 
Bfore there is a for loop to iterate over the rows. the counter is `i`

```
if change.isna(change.iloc[i,3]):
         continue
```

Can't figure out why I receive the

```
**TypeError**: isna() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Because I just pass one argument.... Or am I wrong?

Comment: Try `pd.isna(change.iloc[i,3])` as if condition (or `pandas`, it depends how you imported the module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positional argument `isna` takes is `self`, because you're calling the method of `pd.Dataframe` (`change.isna()`). You're passing one argument, but that's the *second* argument to the function, hence the error.

Take a look at [`pd.Dataframe.isna`'s documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html): there is only `self` specified as argument. This is, because `isna` actually returns a boolean array where *for each element in the dataframe* it tells you whether it's a valid value or NA.

```
if change.iloc[i].isna()[3]:
  ....
```

Alternatively, use the function [`pandas.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html), which takes exactly one object as argument:

```
if pd.isna(change.iloc[i,3]):
  ....
```